# Find out if a website is using Sass and see the original code

Tags: sass, reverse-engineering

Is there any way to find out if a website is using Sass and get access to the original source code? Are there plugins for this? I'm learning Sass and would like to inspect the source of some websites.

PS: Some of the websites I'd like to view use CSS Frameworks.

Comment: If you want to learn about Sass, there are hundreds of Sass projects on Github you can view the source of.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, sometimes. The `.css` file can end with:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=somefile.css.map
```

and then you can open this `.map` file (which is plain JSON) and retrieve the source list. However, more often than not you won't see source maps and source files available at production servers; this functionality is normally only used during development, see [Working with CSS preprocessors](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors) in Chrome Developer Tools docs.